# Grails 2.1.2 - UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES Error

Tags: grails

Am using Grails 2.1.2 on Windows 7 64-Bit System, at the time of compile it gives below error, kindly help me how to fix this.

```
 ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

 ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

 ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

 :: org.grails.plugins#mail;1.0-SNAPSHOT: not found

 :: org.grails.plugins#tomcat;1.3.2: not found

 :: org.grails.plugins#hibernate;1.3.2: not found

 :: org.grails.plugins#csl-rest-lib;1.0: not found

 ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Answer (score 0):

In BuildConfig.groovy, try to declare the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:mail:1-0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:tomcat:1.3.2'
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application was updated from grails 1.3 (<2.*) or create from grails 2.*, you need to check plugins version on the [grails plugins](http://grails.org/plugins/)
For example, current version of mail plugin is 1.0.1 [mail plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/mail)
And also you need to check this dependencies at conf/BuildConfig.groovy. It must have part like this:

```
plugins {
        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

        runtime ":hibernate:${grailsVersion}"
        runtime ":resources:1.1.6"
...
```

Describe your plugins at `plugins` part.
And you need to check latest libraries for plugins and describe it like this:

```
dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

        compile('org.apache.poi:poi:3.7',
                'org.apache.poi:poi-contrib:3.6',
                'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.7',
                'antlr:antlr:2.7.6',
                'org.apache.ant:ant-apache-log4j:1.7.1'
..
```